# Call an api service inside a loop

Tags: angular

I have a function that uses 2 api calls - `deletePart()` and `deleteMapTableEntry()`.

```
handleDeleteForPartsEdit(){
    this.mapTableValuesToDelete = this.allMapTable.filter(element => element.partId == this.deleteId);
    this.apiService.deletePart(this.deleteId).subscribe(data => {
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < this.mapTableValuesToDelete.length; i++) {
      this.apiService.deleteMapTableEntry(this.mapTableValuesToDelete[i].id).subscribe(data => {this.modalService.dismissAll()});
      console.log(this.mapTableValuesToDelete[i].id)
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately I get a 500 error whenever the deleteMapTableEntry service is hit (given ID must not be null).

The service functions:

```
deletePart(id: number): Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.delete(this.apiBaseUrl + '/parts/' + id);
  }

deleteMapTableEntry(partId: any): Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.delete(this.apiBaseUrl + '/parts/mapTable/' + partId);
  }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your object have 2 different ids? `id` and `partId`?

Comment: `id` is the primary key of `this.mapTableValuesToDelete` and `partId` is just a field in `allMapTable`

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, it's very silly. My backend's actual id parameter for deleteMapTableEntry() wasn't set...

Comment: Okay. That happens. Glad you found it. :)